# How to Generate build APK for android in React Native 0.71.2

Tags: react-native

I have created a new project using react native version "0.71.2" . In APK the assets are not bundling and there is no option of bundleInDebug in Build.gradle

expecting to generate the build APK with bundling js and assets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Build Debug with assets:**

You can build a debug version using this steps:

1. Create an assets directory using (One Time Step)

```
mkdir ./android/app/src/main/assets/
```

2. create a blank file with the name index.android (One Time Step)

```
touch ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android
```

3. bundle the app using

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/
react_native_generate_debug_apk1
```

or

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets /index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

4. Build the debug APK using

```
cd android/ 
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

**Build Release with assets:**

And you can build a release version which is much easier using this command:

```
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: didn't help,

asking about react-native latest version 0.70.2

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I edit the answer can you check if the or method work for you.

Comment: Can you run this command and try to build again `npm install -i -g --force react-native-cli`

Comment: universalApk true 

.....make it true , than execute the commands it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

This is what ultimately worked for me after some trial and error.

Note: I'm running this in GitHub Actions which is why I am using `npx` but if running locally and you have the React Native CLI installed you don't need the  `npx` in step 3.

1. Create assets directory:

```
mkdir ./android/app/src/main/assets/
```

2. Create bundle output file (I tried with just `index.android` first and it didn't work)

```
touch ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
```

3. Bundle app

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

4. Create Android debug build

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

I did these steps in GitHub Actions and was able to run the output `.apk` on an Android Emulator. Hope that helps!